# How to adjust weight data for gender and batch

Tags: dataset, biostatistics, ranking, adjustment

I have weights from mice raised in 10 batches. I want to adjust the weights for the gender and batch of the mice, so that I can select the heaviest and lightest for further testing. I know I can do such adjustments as part of various analyses, but I'm not looking to do any such analyses at this point. I just want to rank the mice based on adjusted weights.

I thought this would be fairly straightforward, but it is hard to find info on this. Maybe I've misunderstood something or I'm not searching the right terms. How should I do this?

Comment: If you mean to remove gender and batch effects from the comparison, why not just fit a linear regression mdel with dummys for gender and batch, and rank according to the residuals?

Comment: Please say more about what you mean by "so that I can select the heaviest and lightest for further testing." Selecting the extreme cases for further testing might lead to bias in results. If you do need to use extreme cases, Is there some reason why you can't just take the heaviest and lightest male and female in each "batch"?